# Why is my list->next pointer affected by free()?

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I'm trying to implement a linked list and adding nodes to it. I encountered the following problem, when I try to free the pointer `n` after setting `list->next` to point to the same address of `n`, the `int` value inside the second node also changes to garbage value when I print it again. I want to know if inside the memory, `n` and `list->next` is stored as two separate pointers that hold the same value or it is stored as a single pointer? And if they were distinct, then why freeing `n` also affect `list->next`? Furthermore if freeing `n` make the second node became lost, then why I can still use the `list->next->next` pointer to add a third node, was `list->next->next` pointer also some random value that points to a random usable location ? Here is my code, sorry if my question is too vague, I'm trying my best to understand all this pointers.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main(void) {
    node a;
    a.number = 1;
    a.next = NULL;
    node *list = NULL;
    list = &a;           // the first node
    printf("%i \n", a.number);

    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node)); // creating pointer to the second node
    if (n != NULL) {
        n->number = 2;
        n->next = NULL;
    }

    list->next = n; // add the node to the list

    printf("%p \n%p \n", n, list->next);   // print out the address and value
    printf("%i \n", list->next->number);

    free(n);

    printf("%p \n%p \n", n, list->next);   // print out the address and value
    printf("%i \n", list->next->number);

    n = malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("%p \n%p \n", n, list->next);
    if (n != NULL) {
        n->number = 3;
        n->next = NULL;
    }
    list->next->next = n;
    printf("%i\n", (*(*(*list).next).next).number);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
1 
0x5562319d62a0 
0x5562319d62a0 
2 
0x5562319d62a0 
0x5562319d62a0 
1445140950 
0x5562319d62a0 
0x5562319d62a0 
3
```

Comment: `list->next = n;`, then `free(n)`, leaves `list->next` holding a *dangling* pointer value. Dereferencing it (ex: `list->next->number`) invokes *undefined behavior*. I don't understand why you're freeing `n` in the first place. You're purposely hanging it as the next node in your list. Why do that, then throw it away and dangle a pointer?

Comment: They're two variables that both contain the same value. When you free the memory, it becomes unusable via either variable.

Comment: A couple of syntactic suggestions (but not answers): `node a = {.number=1, .next=NULL};` and `node *list = &a;`. Also, note that you use `n` on the assumption that `malloc` worked when you access `list->next->number` and `free(n)` but there is no guarantee at that point that the allocation succeeded. You may want to return from `main` if `!n` after the allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment

```
list->next = n
```

doesn't *copy* the allocated memory. It just add another pointer pointing to the same memory.

If we "draw" it, before the assignment it looks something like this:

```
+---+      +-----------------+
| n | ---> | memory for node |
+---+      +-----------------+
```

Then after the assignment you have:

```
+---+     
| n | -----------\
+---+            |     +-----------------+
                  >--> | memory for node |
+------------+   |     +-----------------+
| list->next | --/
+------------+
```

Then you pass `n` to `free` leading to this situation:

```
+---+     
| n | -----------\
+---+            |     
                  >--> ???
+------------+   |     
| list->next | --/
+------------+
```

After the call to `free`, the pointer `list->next` is invalid. Any attempt to dereference it will lead to *undefined behavior*.